# Error when trying to save a Bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap, stream, httpwebrequest, webrequest

When I try to save [this image](http://www.modaelinizde.com/images/products/00/28/54/2854_buyuk_zoom.jpg) it gives me that error

> A generic error occurred in GDI+

Full Save path is `C:\Users\BLUE\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ModaelinizdeZoomİmage\ModaelinizdeZoomİmage\bin\Debug\DVKZM237735\2854_buyuk_zoom.jpg`

array[1]= `DVKZM237735`

My code:

```
WebRequest req;
req = WebRequest.Create(et.GetAttribute("src"));

using (var imagestream = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
{
   using (var img = Image.FromStream(imagestream))
   {
      var bmp = new Bitmap(img);
      bmp.Save(array[1] + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(et.GetAttribute("src")));//Error
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show your full save path, e.g. what is in array[1] ?

Comment: @PaulZahra I upgraded post have a look

Comment: Seems as though you have over simplified saving a stream, take a look at the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462256/get-an-image-from-a-url-but-it-is-not-loaded-completely

Comment: @PaulZahra Yeah very thanks worked. It saved my life and lots of time :))

Comment: Ok sweet I'll put that as an answer so that this isn't another question filling up the unanswered pile. ;)